# Find object by index and replace it with other object. (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have below array

```
var a = [{'error': 0 , 'link': 'www.abc.com'},{'error': 1 , 'link': 'www.xyz.com'},{'error': 2 , 'link': 'www.bbc.com'}]
```

Now I want to replace below object at the place of index 1 using lodash

```
var b = {'error': 1 , 'link': 'www.change.com'}
```

So output should be below array

```
a = [{'error': 0 , 'link': 'www.abc.com'},{'error': 1 , 'link': 'www.change.com'},{'error': 2 , 'link': 'www.bbc.com'}]
```

But i dont want to do it by a[1] = b . 
It is creating problem in reducer state .
I want to slice a and just add b in 1st index.

Comment: No need for lodash? `a[1] = b` ? ...

Comment: a[1].link = 'www.change.com'

Comment: @FelixKling, i think, Kalashir need immutability (he uses redux).

Comment: @Yuriy: Maybe. Not a lot of info in the question.

Comment: @FelixKling I dont want to do it lik
e a[1] = b. It is wrong implimentation in reducer. I want to slice the array and want to assign b in a.

Comment: `[a[0], b, ...a.slice(2)]` or `var newArr = a.slice(); newArr[1] = b;`.

Comment: the issue is you are mutating state in your reducer instead of returning a new instance of your state. `const newState = [].concat(state)` then you can do `newState[1].link = 'whatever I want'` just remember to return the newState in your case statement so that you assign a new state object in your reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you absolutely need to keep that array structure and use lodash, this will do the trick:

```
const a = [{error: 0 , link: 'www.abc.com'}, {error: 1 , link: 'www.xyz.com'}, {error: 2 , link: 'www.bbc.com'}];
const b = {error: 1 , link: 'www.change.com'};
const c = _.map(a, item => item.error === b.error ? _.merge(item, b) : item);
```

As Redux uses immutability, you don't really want to mutate `a`. You need to create a new array with the transformation that you want, in this case `const c`.

In the snippet above, `c = [{error: 0 , link: 'www.abc.com'}, {error: 1 , link: 'www.change.com'}, {error: 2 , link: 'www.bbc.com'}]`, which is what you're after.

`_.map` returns a new array as opposed to mutating the existing one, so `const a` and `const b` will stay as they are, while `const c` will be a merge of the two.

---

It may be a good idea to write code that is extendable to other scenarios. The example above relies on `const b`, which may constrain your code.

I suggest creating an anonymous `replaceErrorLink` function that you can use for other cases, like so (note: this uses ES6 syntax):

```js
const a = [{error: 0 , link: 'www.abc.com'}, {error: 1 , link: 'www.xyz.com'}, {error: 2 , link: 'www.bbc.com'}];


const replaceErrorLink = collection => (error, link) => _.map(collection, item => item.error === error ? {...item, link} : item);

const b = replaceErrorLink(a)(1, 'www.change.com');
const c = replaceErrorLink(a)(2, 'www.changezz.com');
const d = replaceErrorLink(b)(2, 'www.changezz.com');

console.log('a: ', a); // note that a didn't mutate
console.log('b: ', b);
console.log('c: ', c);
console.log('d: ', d);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```